# What tool can I use to analyze why my web page takes 30 seconds to load in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, page-load-time

My home page takes 30 seconds to load in IE. It's completely blank for 30 seconds.

The home page loads instantly in Chrome and Firefox.

Is there some sort of tool I can use to analyze this IE issue? Or is there some other approach I can take to identify the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Internet Explorer Developer Tool

[More info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952(v=vs.85).aspx)